# Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000' error when using python-decouple to set ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django

When my `settings.py` has `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []` - the server works fine. But When I do `ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS')` - it gives the error:

```
DisallowedHost at /admin/login/
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add '127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

However when I go into python shell I'm successfully able to import `ALLOWED_HOSTS` - and it prints `[]` which is the correct value.

Any reason why I still get the error?

PS: The `config` is a feature of the `python-decouple` package - used to store sensitive values.

Comment: Is `DEBUG` true or false?

Comment: `DEBUG` is set to `True`

Answer (score 5):

The python-decouple [readme](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple/blob/master/README.rst#understanding-the-cast-argument) suggests thay you have to cast the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to a list. The example it gives is:

```
os.environ['ALLOWED_HOSTS'] = '.localhost, .herokuapp.com'
config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=lambda v: [s.strip() for s in v.split(',')])
```

You appear to be doing `config('ALLOWED_HOSTS')`, so perhaps your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is being evaluated as a string `'[]'` instead of an empty list `[]`.

Comment: `config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=lambda v: [s.strip() for s in v.split(',')])` fixes the problem - thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

In this case django expected a list in ALLOWED_HOSTS, but environment variables are just a plan text, you have to convert before use it, fortunately python decouple has a optional parameter called cast

Consider the following .env file:

.env

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1, .herokuapp.com
DEBUG=True
PORT=5403
```

To access these values in your setting.py you have to import the util class Csv, it will convert a plan string in a list, but pay attention in your .env file or environment variable don't forget to separate the values with comma and space (, ).
For built-in types you don't need to import any aditional class, you can use int, str, bool...

setting.py

```
from decouple import config, Csv

ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', default=[], cast=Csv())
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)
PORT= config('PORT', cast=int)
```